# Global Time Issue

Tags: outlook

I have a scenario regarding sending a meeting request over Outlook for a particular day (let's say December 25th). The meeting request picks the time of initial location and calculates equivalent time in other locations. I would want it to be the local time in each location. As on the 25th of December in India as well as on the 25th of December in US. Your help is appreciated.

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - all appointment times are stored in the UTC time zone, and Outlook always shows the time in the local TZ.

If you want the appointment to be in a particular TZ, set the AppoimtmentItem.StartTimeZone and EndTimeZone properties accordingly before sending a meeting invitation for an attendee in each time zone.